# How to show stable releases in Android Studio(Project Structure)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

In Android Studio under Project Structure/Suggestions it shows the updates suggested for the dependencies in the project modules as show below:
[image]

The problem is it's showing the latest release even if it's beta or alpha, is it possible to show the latest stable versions only?

Comment: Are you using a Stable Release of Android Studio? If you are this shouldn't be happening.

Comment: This happens to me too on Android Studio 3.4.2